# What's better in the following context "let's move to" / "let's go to" / "let's pass to"?

Tags: word-choice

What's more appropriate to be written in the presentation (PowerPoint) when I want continue to the next / following slide with a new subject (or sub-subject)?

> 1) Let's **go** to (the next issue, the following slide)
>
> 2) Let's **move** to (the next issue, the following slide)
>
> 3) Let's **pass** to (the next issue, the following slide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Go* or *move* or even *continue* are fine. (*Pass* sounds unnatural in American English.)

While giving the presentation, you could also say *go on*, *move on* or *continue on* when you have stayed on one point for a long time (maybe there was some discussion about it by the audience) and need to move on to the next slide.

Comment: I mean that I'm writing these words on the presentation, as part of the theoretic.

Comment: Yes, and the first part of my answer addresses (answers) that. The second part of my answer was additional information that flows naturally from the first, as far as language usage goes. So, to repeat, you can write: *let's go to* or *let's move to* or *let's continue to*, but not, in American English, *let's pass to*.